# how to retrive php query from db and set on textarea with executed?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code which selects from DB and sets the image tag.

```
<div>
    <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company where sn='1'");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $logo = $rows['logo'];
            $password = $rows['password'];
            $phone = $rows['phone'];
        }
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $logo ?>"/>
</div>
```

When we get this and set on textarea then we want this query{which save in db} executed. and output show only Logo name.

But this time this show full query which save in db.
we want get this output on textarea:

```
<div><img src="logoname"/></div>
```

Comment: Then you would have to place it between the <textarea> tags...

Comment: You cant place the img tag inside <textarea> because its text input type. If you want to show img inside textarea then you have to position the image in css. refer here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `mysql` extension, which is deprecated. You should use `mysqli` instead.

The loop overwrites your variables (`$logo`, `$password`, `$phone`) in every iteration, so it makes no sense until you're fetching single row.

But if you're fetching single row, then you don't need a loop:

```php
<?php
if ($r = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM company WHERE sn = 1")) {
  $company = mysqli_num_rows($r) ? mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0] : null;
  mysqli_free_result($r);
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo empty($company) ? 'nophoto.png' : $company['logo']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
SELECT * FROM company where sn='1'
```

With

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE sn=1
```

If you take out the apostrophes, that might solve your problem since the value stored in your database is most likely not a string. Also you should have `WHERE` in capital letters.

Let me know if that answered your question! :)

Comment: @Rajesh also, change `where` to `WHERE`, in capital leters. Let me know if it works now

Comment: yes we do. but here problem is the php code and query are same print on textarea . we want only output of query. thanks

Comment: @Rajesh what do you mean "are same print on textarea"?

Comment: <div>
<?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company where sn='1'");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
        $logo = $rows['logo'];
        $password = $rows['password'];
        $phone = $rows['phone'];
        }
        ?>
<img src="<?php echo $logo ?>"/>
</div>

Comment: this query is not run.. we want output of this query: div><img src="logoname"></div>

Comment: @Rajesh Ok and what output are you having right now? I now understand what you want, but what output do you have currently with the above code?

Comment: <div> <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company where sn='1'"); while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { $logo = $rows['logo']; $password = $rows['password']; $phone = $rows['phone']; } ?> <img src="<?php echo $logo ?>"/> </div>

Comment: @Rajesh No that is not the output. That is the code you have. I am asking what the code renders. What do you see on the page when you run the code?

Comment: ye i want to explain you here.. this code is dispaly in output on textarea.... i want this code is execute and show <div><img src="logoname"></div> on textarea.